# Динамическое изменение вложенных в ControlTemplate элементов XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Есть XAML страница с пустым `Pivot` и шаблон для `PivotItem`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="PivotItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>                            
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Сами `PivotItem` добавляются динамически:

```
    private void CreatePivots()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < SomeCount; i++)
        {
            PivotItem MyItem = new PivotItem() { Style =   Resources["MyStyle"] as Style };
            MyPivot.Items.Add(MyItem);
        }
    }
```

Как мне динамически задать `Text` для `TextBlock` внутри `ControlTemplate`?
Что-то вроде `<TextBlock Text={Bindimg Text}/>`, но никак не удается воздействовать на такую конструкцию из под метода в Behind Code.

Comment: А вы хотите для разных элементов разный `Binding`, или везде один и тот же?

Comment: У разных элементов разный текст, он будет доступен внутри цикла. Но разметка одинакова.

Comment: Тогда делайте не так. Положите текст в одно и то же свойство в коллекции, и привяжитесь к этой коллекции через `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Покопал в сторону `ItemsSource`, интересная штука. Она позволила мне перенести создание `PivotItem` из `C#` в `XAML`, а в цикле я просто формирую свою коллекцию. Я думаю так правильнее, но вот уже третий час идет, как я не могу добиться желаемого эффекта. Что я делаю неправильно? [мой код](http://pastebin.com/HCgvycVA)

Comment: Сам отвечу. При использовании `ItemsSource` Нужно определить `ItemTemplate` для `Pivot`, тогда все заработает.

Comment: Может, опубликуете код ответом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить с помощью `ItemsSource`.

```
    <Pivot x:Name="MyPivot">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding myText}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding amount}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

В С# код

```
var MyData = list<MyObj>;   /*MyObj - объект с данными для страничек Pivot'а
                              Содержит в себе поля myText, date и amount*/
MуPivot.ItemsSource = MyData;
```

Благодаря `ItemsSource` не нужно создавать элементы Pivot'a в коде, как я это делал в вопросе.